# uninitialized constant Mandrill::API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mandrill

I'm getting uninitialized constant Mandrill::API in my rails application.
I've added `mandrill-api`  in Gemfile and did bundle.
my `irb` and `rail console` showing different results for `Mandrill.constants`

irb
[:Error, :ValidationError, :InvalidKeyError, :PaymentRequiredError, :UnknownSubaccountError, :UnknownTemplateError, :ServiceUnavailableError, :UnknownMessageError, :InvalidTagNameError, :InvalidRejectError, :UnknownSenderError, :UnknownUrlError, :UnknownTrackingDomainError, :InvalidTemplateError, :UnknownWebhookError, :UnknownInboundDomainError, :UnknownInboundRouteError, :UnknownExportError, :IPProvisionLimitError, :UnknownPoolError, :NoSendingHistoryError, :PoorReputationError, :UnknownIPError, :InvalidEmptyDefaultPoolError, :InvalidDeleteDefaultPoolError, :InvalidDeleteNonEmptyPoolError, :InvalidCustomDNSError, :InvalidCustomDNSPendingError, :MetadataFieldLimitError, :UnknownMetadataFieldError, :Templates, :Exports, :Users, :Rejects, :Inbound, :Tags, :Messages, :Whitelists, :Ips, :Internal, :Subaccounts, :Urls, :Webhooks, :Senders, :Metadata, :API]
which includes :API and works fine,

But when it comes in console,
[:Templates, :Exports, :Users, :Rejects, :Inbound, :Tags, :Messages, :Whitelists, :Ips, :Internal, :Subaccounts, :Urls, :Webhooks, :Senders, :Metadata]
this is what I am getting. any ways??

Comment: There are a lot of answered questions about is on StackOverflow:
look [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582435/delayed-job-and-mandrill-uninitialized-constant-mandrillapi) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869292/gem-not-initializing-when-running-job-from-worker) and so on.

Comment: @EugeneTkachenko I was not calling by using any scheduler method but direct way (from console with UserMailer.sample_method(1).deliver

Comment: what happens when you run Mandrill::API.new ?

Comment: @mylescc I got the issue..answered to this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we are using gem 'mandrill-api' in rails application we have to give like this in Gemfile

```
gem 'mandrill-api', require: 'mandrill'
```

And it worked well after this change.

Comment: The people at mandrillapp.com need to update their doc with this.

Comment: I personally prefer to declare `require: 'mandrill'` in file where I use `Mandrill::API` (in my case it was in `mailer/application_mailer.rb` ), this way gives me expressiveness to my code